# Keydown and Mouseclick calling same function but behaving differently

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

I have a react component consisting of an input box, a button and an initially hidden result box. There is a function which makes an async call to the REST API, gets the data, and displays it in the result box (making it visible). I want that function to be called either on button click, or on pressing enter.

For button click, I have:

```
<button onClick={this.myFunc}>
```

For enter key, I have:

```
<input onKeyUp={this.keyHandler}>
keyHandler = (e) => {
if(e.key === "Enter"){ //tried keycode too
this.myFunc(); }}
```

---

I have a state variable isResultLoaded which sets the visibility of the result box, i.e. when myFunc fetches the results from API, isResultLoaded is set to true which makes the result box visible.

**THE PROBLEM:** When i click on the button, the result box is displayed perfectly. But when i press the enter key, the result is loaded, and isResultLoaded is also set to true (i logged it on console), but the result box still doesn't appear.

```
style={{ visibility: this.state.isResultLoaded ? "visible" : "hidden" }} // For result box
```

Why are there 2 different behaviors? And how do i solve this issue?

**UPDATE:** There is a line in myFunc() which focuses on the result box, which was causing this issue. On commenting the line, both Keydown and Mouseclick are working fine. But i need that line to implement a feature.

```
document.getElementById("result-box").focus(); //tabindex is set to 0
```

Any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code

Use `onkeypress` so it will work correctly

```js
function keyHandler(e){
  if(e.key === "Enter"){ //tried keycode too
    myFunc(); 
  }
}


function myFunc(){
  console.log('running...')
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onClick="myFunc()">test</button>
  <input onkeypress="keyHandler(event)">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I updated my question after figuring out the line which was causing this problem. Changing onKeyDown/Up with onKeyPress solved my problem thanks to you. But can you please explain what focusing the div was doing which onKeyUp/Down couldn't handle but onKeyPress could? I am confused by this behaviour

Comment: See my next ans

Comment: if this works please accept ans so other user can know

Answer (score 0):

`keydown`

Fires when the user depresses a key. It repeats while the user keeps the key depressed.

`keypress`

Fires when an actual character is being inserted in, for instance, a text input. It repeats while the user keeps the key depressed.

`keyup`

Fires when the user releases a key, after the default action of that key has been performed.

`textinput`

Fires when a character is actually added to a control. So if the user presses a character key, but the default is prevented onkeydown or onkeypress, the textinput event does not fire since the sequence does not result in a character being added.